# Vendor App does not work with Salesforce Authenticator

Tags: authentication, app, two-factor-authentication

I am trying to explain to a vendor that their app does not work with Salesforce Authenticator.

The user opens the app, logs into Salesforce, get told to authenticate, authenticate. Then reopen the vendor app which resets to the login screen. Repeat ad infinitum.

I am trying to explain what they are doing wrong but I don't have the right language. Can anyone help with the wording? I posited that the app wasn't retaining the session so when the Authenticator is prompted, the original app session drops... But this is just a guess.

Can anyone help with the wording?

edit: Additional evidence: I tried the app on my iPad with the Authenticator app on my iPhone. The process worked fine.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "app" and what its relation to Salesforce is? It sounds like this is a mobile app, and it uses OAuth to Salesforce for its primary authentication. How are you using Salesforce Authenticator - push notifications or generating a TOTP?

Comment: @ThomasTaylor Yes, it is a mobile application. Using as a push notification.